# Batch file to compare 2 folders

Tags: batch-file

How would I be able to create a batch file to compare 2 folders with the same set of files but different modified date? I have check for some codes in the internet but it would only check if the file exist in the other folder.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? - and possibly which command itepreter?

Comment: Is the modified date different on the folders or the files inside?

Comment: @MortenSickel I'm guessing from the tag it's cmd on windows.

Comment: it is cmd on Windows. The modified date is different on the files inside the folder. I would like to verify if there difference in the file based on the modified date. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
Set folder1=c:\first folder
Set folder2=c:\second folder
Cd /D "%folder1%"
For %%a in (*.*) do (
   For %%b in ("%folder2%\%%a") do (
      If "%%~Ta" neq "%%~Tb" echo Different date/time in file %%a
   )
)
```

You may compare just the date splitting the result of `%%~T...` in variables, and then comparing the variables.

You may also check if the file does not exist in second folder, or compare their sizes, etc...

Comment: I tested it and it only seems to use the "created date" .  It seems that this guy is wanting a diff of the "modified date" instead, right?

Comment: this seems to be working fine with me. the only problem is the change of directory (CD). i have tried removing the CD and placed
For For %%a in (%folder1%*.*) do (

it would make tag all the files from the directory as with different date.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in ("folder1" "folder2") do (
forfiles /p %%a /c "cmd /c @echo @file @fdate"
) >>dates.txt
```

That will output the files in both folders with their modified date next to them into a file named dates.txt so you can compare.

If you need to compare them in some other way please specify.

Comment: I would love to test this but XP does not seem to recognize forfiles. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would try Robocopy from the MS Resource Kit:

```
ROBOCOPY %SOURCE_DIR% %TARGET_DIR% * /MIR /XO /L
```

The "/L" specifies test mode and so it won't actually copy files.  It just shows the different files.