# Batch file to compare the same files in two folders

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file to compare two folders with the same set of files and copy any files that are different in size from one folder to the other. I tried to adapt the answer from another question as follows as a starting point, but even this doesn't work.

```
@echo off
Set folder1="C:\folder1"
Set folder2="C:\folder2"
Cd /D "%folder1%"
For %%a in (*.*) do (
   For %%b in ("%folder2%\%%a") do (
      If "%%~Za" neq "%%~Zb" echo Different file size in %%a
   )
)
```

Update1:
I figured out what was wrong in the example above; it was the quotes around the directories in the set folder commands. The following works as it should:

```
@echo off
Set folder1=C:\folder1
Set folder2=C:\folder2
Cd /D "%folder1%"
For %%a in (*.*) do (
   For %%b in ("%folder2%\%%a") do (
      If %%~za neq %%~zb echo Different file size %%a
   )
)
```

Update2:
So this finally does what I want (compares two folders with the same set of files and copies any files that are different in size from one folder to the other):

```
@echo off
Set folder1=C:\folder1
Set folder2=C:\folder2
Cd /D "%folder1%"
For %%a in (*.*) do (
   For %%b in ("%folder2%\%%a") do (
      If %%~za neq %%~zb xcopy "%folder1%\%%a" "%folder2%" /y
   )
)
```

Comment: What isn't working - what are you expecting to happen that isn't - what errors (if any) are you receiving?

Comment: What was the other question? Can you link to it?

Comment: Maybe Robocopy also has a DIFF function?

Comment: @fvrghl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839897/batch-file-to-compare-2-folders

Comment: @unclemeat it echos "Different file size in..." for every file in the folders even if they are the same size. It also echos the same statement twice for each if that matters.

Comment: I ended up using `GTR` instead of `neq` that you used in your `if` statement. Thank you though! Huge timesaver!

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to do this is

```
xcopy /L /y /d "directory1\*" "directory2"
```

The `/L` LISTS the files that would be copied. `/d` actually says "if the source file in the first parameter is later than the file in the second" which may not be what you want. The `/y` prevents a prompt for ovewrite (with the `/L` switch, just a listing is created, but still...)

Files existing in the source but not in the destination will be copied to the destination (or listed if the `/L` switch is used)

Remove the `/L` switch to actually perform the copy.

Add `/s` to repeat for all subdirectories of the source.

Comment: I want to copy based on file size and not timestamp.